# How to take a variable in my java file and connect it to an XML file

Tags: java, android, xml

Having trouble with a [weatherapp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPPot.png) project. The requirements are :

1. Design the UX for "Now" and 3 days in the future
2. Design the Java code for the variables (hard code for now)
3. Connect the java values to the UX so it shows on the page what you have coded in Java. My code looks like :

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {//start class

   int now = 45;
   int todayHigh = 56;
   int todayLow = 40;
   int tomHigh = 70;
   int tomLow = 40;
   int thurHigh = 45;
   int thurLow = 42;




   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   }

   private void displayNow(int now)
   {
       TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.now);
       quantityTextView.setText(now);
   }
   ```

   and the xml file looks like

   ```
           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/now"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:padding="16dp"
               android:textSize="20sp"
               android:text="Now: "/>
           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/today"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:padding="16dp"
               android:textSize="20sp"
               android:text="Today: "/>
           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/tomorrow"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:padding="16dp"
               android:textSize="20sp"
               android:text="Tomorrow: "/>
           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/thursday"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:padding="16dp"
               android:textSize="20sp"
               android:text="Thursday: "/>
   </LinearLayout>
   ```

Basically i'm trying to get the variable i have for now (int now =45) to display next to the text view i labeled "now" when i run the app, but nothing is showing. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You forgot to call displayNow(now); method inside in OnCreate()

Answer (score 0):

Inside OnCreate() call displayNow

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        displayNow(now);
    }
```

Comment: Just tried your suggestion, when I ran the app again it instantly closed and gave me the "has stopped working error" i tried running the debugger and got **edit** tried posting the error message but was too long by about 5,000 characters haha. Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2d

Comment: "FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.android.sunshine, PID: 7876
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.sunshine/com.example.android.sunshine.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2d
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665) " Just that or 4-5 lines at a time? sorry lol new to stackoverflow, you guys are really helpful tho!

Comment: It is not able to find some resource defined in the xml. You need to find the line number mentioned in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {//start class

int now;
int todayHigh;
int todayLow;
int tomHigh;
int tomLow;
int thurHigh;
int thurLow;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      now = 45;
      todayHigh = 56;
      todayLow = 40;
      tomHigh = 70;
      tomLow = 40;
      thurHigh = 45;
       thurLow = 42;

    TextView quantityTextView = (TextView)    findViewById(R.id.now);
   displayNow(int now)

}

private void displayNow(int nowInt)
{
    quantityTextView.setText(nowInt);
}}
```